# Is there a way to configure SSO oauth2 Prometheus via Nginx Ingress and Oauth2-proxy

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak, prometheus

I want all users who access Prometheus GUI to be able to log in via SSO keycloak which supports the oauth2 protocol, but now the current configuration, before reaching prometheus gui, there is an nginx server and on the upstreams I have several websites like: grafana , prometheus etc. I searched on the google what is the best solution to do that and I found the Oauth2-proxy that can be done this but after the authentication, the oauth2-proxy is redirect me to the auth page and not to prometheus, everything works ok but not the redirect url.

**nginx.conf**

```
user root;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;


        listen 443 ssl default_server;
        server_name example.com;

        location /oauth2/ {
                proxy_pass       http://127.0.0.1:4180;
                proxy_set_header Host                    $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Scheme                $scheme;
                proxy_set_header X-Auth-Request-Redirect "https://example.com/prometheus";
        }

        location = /oauth2/auth {
                proxy_pass       http://127.0.0.1:4180;
                proxy_set_header Host             $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Scheme         $scheme;
                proxy_set_header Content-Length   "";
                proxy_pass_request_body           off;
        }

        location ^~ /prometheus/  {
                auth_request /oauth2/auth;
                error_page 401 = /oauth2/sign_in;

                auth_request_set $user   $upstream_http_x_auth_request_user;
                auth_request_set $email  $upstream_http_x_auth_request_email;
                proxy_set_header X-User  $user;
                proxy_set_header X-Email $email;

                auth_request_set $token  $upstream_http_x_auth_request_access_token;
                proxy_set_header X-Access-Token $token;

                auth_request_set $auth_cookie $upstream_http_set_cookie;
                add_header Set-Cookie $auth_cookie;

                auth_request_set $auth_cookie_name_upstream_1 $upstream_cookie_auth_cookie_name_1;

                if ($auth_cookie ~* "(; .*)") {
                        set $auth_cookie_name_0 $auth_cookie;
                        set $auth_cookie_name_1 "auth_cookie_name_1=$auth_cookie_name_upstream_1$1";
                }

                if ($auth_cookie_name_upstream_1) {
                        add_header Set-Cookie $auth_cookie_name_0;
                        add_header Set-Cookie $auth_cookie_name_1;
                }

                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
                proxy_pass         "http://192.168.1.20:9090/prometheus/"; # This is where my web server is hosted
                }
```

**oauth2-proxy.cfg**

```
provider="keycloak"
provider_display_name="SSO connect"
ssl_insecure_skip_verify=true
login_url="https://auth.keycloak/oauth2/authorize"
redeem_url="https://auth.keycloak/oauth2/token"
validate_url="https://auth.keycloak/oauth2/userinfo"
client_id="8m67vhg34hgj-232k-786j-90cf-45656gjh5f64g"
client_secret="sd;kfposdfk546idfj;"
cookie_secure="true"
redirect_url="https://example.com/prometheus/oauth2/callback"
upstreams="http://192.168.1.20:9090/prometheus/" # My website server
email_domains="*"
cookie_secret="AkaBxYPzIvMdQziWECV6Ow=="
http_address = "127.0.0.1:4180"
https_address = ":443"
reverse_proxy = true
```

oauth2 bin command :

```
[root@nginx]# ./oauth2-proxy --config=/etc/nginx/oauth2-proxy.cfg

[2022/02/03 17:23:54] [proxy.go:89] mapping path "/prometheus/" => upstream "http://192.168.1.20:9090/prometheus/"
[2022/02/03 17:23:54] [oauthproxy.go:148] OAuthProxy configured for Keycloak Client ID: 8m67vhg34hgj-232k-786j-90cf-45656gjh5f64g
[2022/02/03 17:23:54] [oauthproxy.go:154] Cookie settings: name:_oauth2_proxy secure(https):true httponly:true expiry:168h0m0s domains: path:/ samesite: refresh:disabled
```

**The oauth2-proxy port 4180 is listening ok :**

```
[root@nginx]# netstat -naptu | grep 4180
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4180          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      26031/./oauth2-prox
```

**Here is the page of prometheus login point out on oauth2-proxy for authentication**

[image]

**After authentication, is redirect me to the https://auth.keycloak page and not to the upstream https://example.com/prometheus**

[image]

**On the outh2-proxy I have this output whenever I want to access "https://example.com/prometheus"**

```
9 Safari/537.36" 401 13 0.000
[2022/02/03 17:29:59] [validator.go:77] Rejecting invalid redirect "https://example.com": domain / port not in whitelist
[2022/02/03 17:29:59] [director.go:85] Invalid redirect provided in X-Auth-Request-Redirect header: https://example.com
[2022/02/03 17:29:59] [validator.go:77] Rejecting invalid redirect "https://example.com": domain / port not in whitelist
[2022/02/03 17:29:59] [director.go:85] Invalid redirect provided in X-Auth-Request-Redirect header: https://example.com
```

What I'm missing here .. I don't have any ideas anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

**Step1.** Download oauth2-proxy binary - my version is **oauth2-proxy v7.2.1**

**Step2.** Create **oauth2-proxy as services** in order to run "start| stop | status".

```
[root@nginx]# cat oauth2_proxy.service 
[Unit]
Description=oauth2_proxy daemon
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/var/opt/oauth2-proxy --config=/etc/nginx/oauth2-proxy.cfg
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=process
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Running Status oauth2_proxy command**

```
[root@nginx]# systemctl status oauth2_proxy
● oauth2_proxy.service - oauth2_proxy daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/oauth2_proxy.service; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2022-02-08 11:03:05 CET; 1 day 22h ago
 Main PID: 34114 (oauth2-proxy)
   CGroup: /system.slice/oauth2_proxy.service
           └─34114 /var/opt/oauth2-proxy --config=/etc/nginx/oauth2-proxy.cfg

Feb 08 11:03:05 nginx.local systemd[1]: Started oauth2_proxy daemon.
Feb 08 11:03:05 nginx.local oauth2-proxy[34114]: [2022/02/08 11:03:05] [logging.go:27] Redirecting logging to file: /var/log/oauth2/oauth2_proxy.log
```

**Step3.** Create  **ouath2-proxy.cfg** and add the below lines:

```
provider="oidc"
provider_display_name="SSO Connect"
login_url="https://auth.keycloak/oauth2/authorize"
validate_url="https://auth.keycloak/oauth2/token"
profile_url="https://auth.keycloak/oauth2/userinfo"
client_id="8m67vhg34hgj-232k-786j-90cf-45656gjh5f64g"
client_secret="sd;kfposdfk546idfj"
redirect_url="https://example.com/oauth2/callback"
upstreams=["http://192.168.1.20:9090/prometheus/"] # My website server
###OIDC settings
#reverse_proxy=true
oidc_issuer_url="https://auth.keycloak"
insecure_oidc_allow_unverified_email=true

email_domains=["*"]
cookie_secret="AkaBxYPzIvMdQziWECV6Ow=="
http_address="127.0.0.1:4180"
whitelist_domains="tool.example.com"
cookie_domains=["tool.example.com"]
cookie_secure="false"
cookie_samesite="lax"
pass_authorization_header = true
pass_access_token = true
pass_user_headers = true
set_authorization_header = true
set_xauthrequest = true
cookie_refresh = "1m"
cookie_expire = "30m"
scope="openid email profile"
```

**Step4.** Add lines below on **nginx.conf** in order to make the authentication and redirecting to prometheus upstream

```
  location /oauth2/ {
    proxy_pass       http://127.0.0.1:4180;
    proxy_set_header Host                    $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Scheme                $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Auth-Request-Redirect $request_uri;
  }
  location = /oauth2/auth {
    proxy_pass       http://127.0.0.1:4180;
    proxy_set_header Host             $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Scheme         $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Content-Length   "";
    proxy_pass_request_body           off;
  }

  location ^~ /prometheus/ {
    auth_request /oauth2/auth;
    error_page 401 = /oauth2/sign_in;

    auth_request_set $user   $upstream_http_x_auth_request_user;
    auth_request_set $email  $upstream_http_x_auth_request_email;
    proxy_set_header X-User  $user;
    proxy_set_header X-Email $email;

    auth_request_set $auth_cookie $upstream_http_set_cookie;
    add_header Set-Cookie $auth_cookie;

    proxy_pass http://prometheus_backend/prometheus/;
  }
```

I hope you don't have any problems and make it works.